# How to replace proc with unboxed closures?

Tags: rust

I’m struggling a bit with replacing proc. Using `Invoke` works but I have to specify a lifetime. In order to be able to send the enum to another thread I have to use `'static` and later `mem::transmute` to cast the lifetime. Not very appealing.

On the other hand using `FnOnce` gives me this error:

```
<anon>:24:32: 24:33 error: cannot move a value of type for<'r> core::ops::FnOnce(&'r Type) + Send: the size of for<'r> core::ops::FnOnce(&'r Type) + Send cannot be statically determined [E0161]
```

How can I properly replace proc?

```
#![feature(box_syntax)]
#![feature(std_misc)]

use std::mem;
use std::thunk::Invoke;

struct Type;

enum Message {
    Handle(Box<Invoke<(&'static Type)> + Send>) //'
}
enum Message2 {
    Handle(Box<FnOnce(&Type) + Send>)
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = Type;
    let handler = Message::Handle(box move |_| {});
    let handler2 = Message2::Handle(box move |_| {});
    match handler {
        Message::Handle(f) => f.invoke(unsafe {mem::transmute(&a)})
    }
    match handler2 {
        Message2::Handle(f) => f(&a)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in your case is to use the `for` keyword, which allows you to specify an "anonymous" lifetime for your input parameter.

```
#![feature(box_syntax)]
#![feature(std_misc)]

use std::thunk::Invoke;

struct Type;

enum Message {
    Handle(Box<for <'r> Invoke<(&'r Type)> + Send>)
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = Type;
    let handler = Message::Handle(box move |_: &Type| {});
    match handler {
        Message::Handle(f) => f.invoke(&a)
    }
}
```

[playpen link](http://is.gd/2qkyt6)

Also I think the major problem when using your `transmute()` trick would be if your function was returning or storing a reference to a part of the input structure: the compiler would have assigned the 'static lifetime to this reference, whereas it would obviously be a mistake, and may lead to memory corruption.

You can find more information about closures and why the `Invoke` trait is currently needed in [this blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/11/26/purging-proc/) (note: the part about specifying the closure type explicitly is now outdated, the compiler now infers it).

Comment: Thank you! But I think this guy is not documented yet… :(

Comment: You can find some information on the for syntax in the corresponding RFC on github (I haven't found any other documentation on it): https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0387-higher-ranked-trait-bounds.md

Comment: It’s also a bit surprising that one has to annotate the type of the argument when constructing the closure.

Answer (score 3):

What about using [`Thunk`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/thunk/struct.Thunk.html)?

```
#![feature(std_misc)]

use std::thunk::Thunk;

struct Type;

enum Message<'a> { //'
    Handle(Thunk<'a, &'a Type, u8>)
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = Type;
    let handler = Message::Handle(Thunk::with_arg(move |_| 42));
    let res = match handler {
        Message::Handle(f) => f.invoke((&a))
    };
    println!("{}", res);
}
```

([playpen link](http://is.gd/qe0uqb))

> In order to be able to send the enum to another thread I have to use 'static and later mem::transmute to cast the lifetime.

Since [RFC 458](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0458-send-improvements.md) landed, [`thread::scoped`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scoped.html) can accept closures (and `Fn*` traits) that have a non-`'static` lifetime. The caveat is that you have to ensure that the thread exits before the lifetime expires - otherwise you'd have a reference to invalid memory!

Using `mem::transmute` lets you ignore that, but at the cost of your program crashing when that memory is no longer valid.

Comment: Thunk has the same problem as my solution. You have to supply a lifetime and I’m using a channel. See Vaeldens answer. The mysterious `for` is the solution.

Comment: @Ferio I'm glad you got your problem solved! I have to admit that I don't understand *why* you can't supply a lifetime, but that's something I'll have to run into for myself sometime! ^_^

Comment: @Ferio Ah - **channels**! I think that's an important enough distinction to add to your original question. When you said "send the enum to another thread", I just assumed you meant when *starting* the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, use:

```
Handle(Box<FnMut(&Type) + Send>)
```

The more complex answer is, as per https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/test/run-pass/unboxed-closures-prelude.rs, you can't invoke a `Box<FnOnce(...)>`, only a Sized F where F: FnOnce<...>

...no idea why, but I presume its because it moves the value as the trait consumes self; quite strange.

Comment: `FnMut` doesn’t work because it borrows it’s environment which is often not static and thus not sendable. I think I found a better solution for now: `let handler: Box<Invoke<&Type>> = unsafe{mem::transmute(handler)}; handler.invoke(self)`

Comment: But I have no idea what implications this cast has. I hope calling `FnOnce` will be possible soon.

Comment: @Ferio: if you need to transmute, it’s wrong. It *might* function correctly, but you’re definitely asking for trouble and have broken the rules.

Comment: I don’t know why I have to transmute. In principle it should work with `as`, but I guess `FnOnce` is still missing some support…

Comment: @Feno: if you don’t know what you are transmuting from and to, *do not on any account do it*. In your particular case, you’re transmuting from `&'_ Type` to `&'static Type`, which could lead to use-after-free bugs.

Comment: But without `for<'a>` it would have been the only option, „Don’t do it!“ is not an option in that case.

Comment: To clarify, the cast I mentioned in the comment is `Box<FnOnce(&Type) + Send>` to  `Box<Invoke<&Type>>`. This is why I was confused because one should be able to cast this without `transmute`. I didn’t claim it’s a good solution but it is better than casting some `'static` away.